close sol account - rent
Beginner here, I just learned to create wallet with CLI as well as closing token account.
I am now looking to figure out how to also close the sol token account of a wallet.
So that wallet would be completely empty with no rent on it. Is it possible as you need sol for a wallet to function. Can you close it by sending the rent to address? Can it be done through CLI?

To close an account, you must transfer all sol to another account/address.
If an account has no SOL in it to be rent-exempt, it will be purged from the runtime.
If you are referring to wrapped SOL, then you'll need to unwrap it first into regular SOL and transfer it to the new account/address.
guide on wrapped SOL->
https://station.jup.ag/guides/general/wrapped-sol
Wrapped SOL guide in JS -> https://solana.com/developers/cookbook/tokens/manage-wrapped-sol

I was refering to the SOL from the main wallet address on Solana, and trying to recover the rent-exempt balance for that main account itself.
My guess was because the System Account on Solana, which holds the SOL balance of the wallet is different from token accounts used for NFTs or other SPL tokens.
There’s no mechanism to "close" a System Account and recover any SOL associated with the rent -exempt... Or is there a trick using CLI, python or else to close the system account and send the sol  from the rent to another address?

You transfer the sol out of the wallet!!
